# How to handle mongoose database while connection stop

Tags: json, node.js, api, mongoose

I have implemented the mongoose in node js application.I want to handle error in my application while my mongodb connection stop. currently if my node application running and mongodb connection stop then node server crashes.

```
mongoose.connect(config.get('db'), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDb');
    }
    // routes =====================================================
    var router = require('./router/index')(app, passport);

    //error handler ==============================================

    var errorHandler = new ErrorHandler(logger);
    app.use(errorHandler.build());
});
```

if i start my node application without start mongodb connection then node server up but when i hit any api method then mongoose database schema call back function not return any error.

i want to handle mongoose connection failure.Please any one help me

```
User.findOne({ 'local.workEmail': workEmail }, function (err, user) {
                        // if there are any errors, return the error
                        if (err)
                            return done(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the error in the `error` event.
Add this before `mongoose.connect`.

```
mongoose.connection.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log("Could not connect to MongoDb!");
});
```